# How to style Bootstrap menu like a V?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

[image]

Is it possible to style the menu like this (see link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5YB6.jpg) in Bootstrap using CSS?

How to I do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use arrow shape image facing down words in background of the menu.
for bootstrap you can use it in .navbar-default class

```
.navbar-default {
     padding-bottom: 70px;
     background:url('imagename.png') no-repeat bottom center #000;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Vipin!

Thank you for your answer, but I can't get it to work!

I understand you, but when I try to add it in the .navbar-header I get this (http://i.imgur.com/nK8sc1L.png)

And when I add a new class beneath my .navbar-header, it just disappears. 

like:

<div class="navbar-header">
<div class="arrow">
</div>
</div>

Comment: you have to do it with the outer most parent div of menu... by default .navbar-default is the parent of menu. so you can try this with  "navbar-default" this class. ".navbar-header" is a child of navbar-default thats why its  not behaving properly.

Comment: Sorry for that Vipin!

It worked out just fine as you said. Maybe the booze yesterday that made me little bit slow. :P

Though; when I removed the #000; from the background, it turned out good. 

Thank you so much for your support! Two Thumbs up!